# How do I call a Python/Perl script in bin folder from a Bash script?

Tags: python, perl, bash

I previously used to copy Python/Perl scripts to access from my bash script. Duplication is not a good idea I know! Is there a way to call them from bin or libs folder that we have set up?

For instance :

- My python script resides in `/home/ThinkCode/libs/python/script.py`
- My bash script resides in `/home/ThinkCode/NewProcess/ProjectA/run.sh`
- Now I want to use/call `script.py` from `run.sh`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `python /path/to/my/python/script.py`.

Answer (score 4):

Make this the first line of your python script (bash will then know this is a python script and it should be run with python):

```
#/usr/bin/env python
```

*EDIT: my bad, it should be `#!/usr/bin/env python` not `#!/usr/bin/python`. [It is better](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-June/054816.html) to do it this way.*

Then `chmod` your script with `u+x` (if not `a+x`).

Now your python script works as an executable. Your bash script, then, can call it like you'd call any executable.

Answer (score 1):

In a bash script, you execute programs the same way you do from the bash command prompt.

```
/home/ThinkCode/libs/python/script.py
```

If this doesn't launch the script directly, you may need to add `python` to the beginning (like this: `python /home/ThinkCode/libs/python/script.py`) and/or ensure that the script is executable (with `chmod +x /home/ThinkCode/libs/python/script.py`).